# iOS Center few elements in parent

Tags: ios, uiview, position, center

I've an ImageView, a label, and another label in a UIView. My label is below my imageview, and my second label below the first label.

So I've :

```
 UIView : 
    - ImageView
    - Label
    - Label
```

I'm searching a way to do something like "gravity=center" in Android. I want to center all elements created in my UIView. I can easily center horizontally each views with a constraint, but I don't found a method to center vertically all views using the storyboard.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Sounds like UIStackView is what you want

Comment: Indeed, probably best answer, thx !

Answer (score 0):

You should use anotherView. Something like:

```
UIView:
   - AnotherView (UIView) :
       - UIImageView
       - UILabel 
       - UILabel
```

You have to pin the 3 elements to the superView

- What we are trying to do is to make AnotherView to wrap the content, so you should not give a fixed height or width to it. You you should center that view both vertically and horizontally inside it's superview.
- Regarding the subviews, you should pin them to AnotherView.

Hope it helps.